# Won't redirect http://www.domainname.net/ to http://www.domainname.net/news/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.net\/news\/" [R=301,L]
```

Okay I would like to use `cPanel` to redirect:

```
domainname.net/
```

To this path on the same domain:

```
domainname.net/news/
```

Anyways when I enter `domainname.net/` it doesn't redirect as it should.

The `.htacess` I am using is above.

Answer (score 0):

This chunk of code—specifically the last line—seems off:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.net\/news\/" [R=301,L]
```

I would suggest replacing it with this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainname.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ news [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.net$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.net$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname\.net/news/ [R=301,L]
```